# Change name of other Program using c#

Tags: c#, taskmanager

Does anyone know, if it's possible to change the name of an other Program in the Taskmanager using C#?
If yes how, cause I'm currently making a program, which searches **Edge.exe** and then i want it to change the name to **Internet.exe**

Comment: @clemens I think he is asking something different... He is asking to change the name of what appears in TaskManager, not on the file system.

Comment: I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Reopened this...

Comment: Whatever problem this is meant to solve, it's unlikely to work...

Answer (score 3):

So you want to

> change the name of an other Program

but your query is impresise because there is **a difference between the process name and the application name**. The first is taken from the executables version-info resource, and can in C# be accessed by
[`Process.ProcessName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname.aspx) which is a read-only property so you can't set it.

You can't set it using any other method either **for obvious reasons.** Only malware would want to disguise in such a way.

---

**You can however change the application name** instead of the process name because it is linked to the title of the processes main window.

e.g. to change it you could use

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

private void ChangeEdgeToInternet()
{
    foreach(Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Edge"))
    {
        SetWindowText(process.MainWindowHandle, "Internet");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without doing some undocumented memory access. In the end the information shown by the TaskManager in the Name column is taken from [`GetModuleBaseName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684232(v=vs.85).aspx) API. Clearly there is no `SetModuleBaseName()` API. There is another similar API: [`GetProcessImageFileName ()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx), still no set.

Answer (score -3):

You can rename the executable file of the program. Hopefully this will help.

```
System.IO.File.Move(directoryPath+"\\Edge.exe", directoryPath+"Internet.exe");
```